# Where download ws2_32.dll version 2.2 for run function WSPRegisterMemory?

Tags: windows, dll, winsock

Where download ws2_32.dll version 2.2 for run function WSPRegisterMemory? I have winxp sp3 and installed lastest platform SDK and Windows Driver Kit but all ws2_32.dll have version 2.0 and i have 
"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSPRegisterMemory@20" in VS when i compile project. 
But example which check winsock version in system from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742213(VS.85).aspx show result this string "The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay" what i do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

All `WSP*()` functions are part of the Winsock SPI, as opposed to `WSA*()`, which are part of the Winsock API.  The SPI — Service Provider Interface — is for driver-side code, typically drivers implementing Winsock Layered Service Providers (LSP).  If you aren't writing a driver and linking your driver to the Windows DDK libraries, you can't call `WSP*()` functions.

Programs that link to the regular Winsock DLL can only call the API — Application Programming Interface — functions, which includes the `WSA*()` functions plus BSD compatibility functions like `recv()`.

Also, you never copy Winsock DLLs from one system to another.  The one that comes with your OS is the only one you should use.  The DLL just provides an interface to the OS's network stack, so replacing the DLL with one from another source will likely break networking on that system, because the other DLL will be trying to talk to the other OS's low-level network stack interface.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I write LSP dll which changing all receiving traffic and i have probmle with reallocation memory buffer which contains data. This buffers allocate with WSPRegisterMemory so i need use this functions for allocate need memory size. Maybe you know some other ways to achive that? Any advice?

Comment: That's a different question.  Please post it separately.